# Não consegue entra no Memo clicando com o mouse

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10

No meu projeto eu tenho um `TMemo` e um `TDBMemo`, todos eles tem implementado um evento de entrada e de saída do componente, de um tempo para cá começou a da esse erro de não conseguir entrar no memo clicando com o Mouse. não si o que é esta errado pois funcionava tudo bem. vou deixar o código do Form para analise.

Esse é o Form que não consigo entra com o clique do mouse Lembrando que, os Memos não estão desabilitados e não estão somente de leitura.

```
unit UAndamentoProcessual;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, Winapi.ShellAPI, System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants, System.Classes, Winapi.MMSystem,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtDlgs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.DBCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.Buttons, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Data.DB,
  frxClass, frxDBSet, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdMessageClient,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdSMTPBase,
  IdSMTP, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL,
  IdMessage, IdAntiFreezeBase, IdAntiFreeze, IdSASL, IdSASLUserPass,
  IdSASLLogin,
  DBAccess, Uni, MemDS, UniProvider, InterBaseUniProvider, UniDacVcl, DAScript,
  UniScript,
  ACBrBase,ACBrMail, RzEdit, RzDBEdit,
  UFuncoes, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TfrmAndamentoProcessual = class(TForm)
    pnAndamentoProcessualPesquisa: TPanel;
    pnAndamentoProcessualInclusao: TPanel;
    pnAndamentoProcessual:         TPanel;
    pnCabecalhoInclusaoAndamento:  TPanel;
    pnRodapeInclusaoAndamento:     TPanel;
    dbeDataAgenda:                 TDBEdit;
    dbeHoraAgenda:                 TDBEdit;
    dbeResponsavelAgenda:          TDBEdit;
    dbePrazoProcessual:            TDBEdit;
    dbeHoraConclusao:              TDBEdit;
    dbeDataConclusao:              TDBEdit;
    dbeHoraPrazo:                  TDBEdit;
    dbm_Observacao:                TDBMemo;
    dbm_DescricaoAgenda:           TDBMemo;
    dbmProvidencias_Descricao:     TDBMemo;
    dbcFaseProcesso:               TDBComboBox;
    chkAtoFaturavel:               TCheckBox;
    btnNovoAndamento:              TBitBtn;
    btnPublicacao:                 TBitBtn;
    btnAlterarAndamento:           TBitBtn;
    btnConsultas:                  TBitBtn;
    btnVerImprimir:                TBitBtn;
    btnCancelar:                   TBitBtn;
    btnSalvar:                     TBitBtn;
    btnNomeImagemAndamento:        TBitBtn;
    lblObservacao:                 TLabel;
    lblAgenda:                     TLabel;
    lblSolicitadoPor:              TLabel;
    lblSolicitante:                TLabel;
    lblCodAndamento:               TLabel;
    lblRestam:                     TLabel;
    lblRestamAgenda:               TLabel;
    opdNomeImagemAndamento:        TOpenPictureDialog;
    dbmObservacao2:                TMemo;
    btnExcluirAndamento:           TBitBtn;
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNovoAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnAlterarAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MudaCorEntrada(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MudaCorSaida(Sender: TObject);
    procedure opdNomeImagemAndamentoSelectionChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ContadorMax(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSalvarClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnCancelarClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNomeImagemAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnExcluirAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ForcaEntradaClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure PesquisaAndamentos(ProcessoAux: string);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

uses UDataModuleGeral, UDataModuleGeral2, UEntradaSistema, UTelaPrincipal,
  UManutencaoProcessos, UPublicacoes, UConsultas, USplash ,UEnviaEmailClientes,
  UDataModuleRelatorios;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.btnAlterarAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataModuleGeral.tbAgenda.Insert;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.btnCancelarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if frmSplash <> nil then frmSplash.Close;

  memDescricao_Andamento.Clear;
  dbmObservacao2.Lines.Clear;

  DataModuleGeral.tbAgenda.Cancel;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.btnExcluirAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vSQL: String;
  iCod: Integer;
begin
  iCod := DataModuleGeral2.qryPesquisaAndamentosCODIGO_ANDAMENTO.AsInteger;

  vSQL := 'DELETE FROM ANDAMENTOS_PROCESSUAIS WHERE CODIGO_ANDAMENTO = :PCod ';

  DataModuleGeral2.qryAddEdtAnd.Close;
  DataModuleGeral2.qryAddEdtAnd.SQL.Clear;
  DataModuleGeral2.qryAddEdtAnd.SQL.Add(vSQL);
  DataModuleGeral2.qryAddEdtAnd.ParamByName('PCod').AsInteger := iCod;
  if Application.MessageBox('Deseja Realmente EXCLUIR este ANDAMENTO?','Pergunta',
                   MB_YESNO+MB_ICONQUESTION+MB_DEFBUTTON2) <> IDNO then
  begin
    try
      DataModuleGeral2.qryAddEdtAnd.ExecSQL;
    finally
      PesquisaAndamentos(vCampoProcesso);
    end;
  end else
  begin
    btnCancelarClick(Sender);
    Exit;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.btnNomeImagemAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  opdNomeImagemAndamento.Execute;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.btnNovoAndamentoClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    DataModuleGeral.tbAgenda.Append;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.btnSalvarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if DataModuleGeral.tbAgenda.State in [dsInsert,dsEdit] then
  begin
    DataModuleGeral.tbAgendaCODIGO_CLIENTE.AsInteger := DataModuleGeral.tbProcessosCOD_CLIENTE.AsInteger;

    if dbmProvidencias_Descricao.Text <> '' then
    begin
      DataModuleGeral.tbAgenda.Post;
    end else
    begin
      DataModuleGeral.tbAgenda.Cancel;
    end;
  end;

  frmSplash.Close;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.ForcaEntradaClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
// Isso e´o que eu estou usando para poder entrar nos memos com o Clique do Mouse
  if Sender is TMemo       then TMemo(Sender).SetFocus;
  if Sender is TDBMemo     then TDBMemo(Sender).SetFocus;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.ContadorMax(Sender: TObject);
var Min, Total: Integer;
begin

  if Sender is TMemo then
  begin
    //Passando o valor minímo de caracteres do Memo para a variável Min.
    Min   := TMemo(Sender).GetTextLen;
    //Efetuando o cálculo entre o valor máximo e o mínimo.
    Total := TMemo(Sender).MaxLength - Min;
    // Testando se ainda existem caracteres disponíveis para inserir.
    if Total < 1 then
    begin
      lblRestam.Font.Color := clRed;
      lblRestam.Caption := ('Máximo!');
    end else
    begin
      lblRestam.Font.Color := clBlack;
      lblRestam.Caption := ('Restam '+IntToStr(Total));
    end;
  end;

  if Sender is TDBMemo   then
  begin
    //Passando o valor minímo de caracteres do Memo para a variável Min.
    Min   := TDBMemo(Sender).GetTextLen;
    //Efetuando o cálculo entre o valor máximo e o mínimo.
    Total := TDBMemo(Sender).MaxLength - Min;
    // Testando se ainda existem caracteres disponíveis para inserir.
    if Total < 1 then
    begin
      lblRestamAgenda.Font.Color := clRed;
      lblRestamAgenda.Caption    := ('Máximo!');
    end else
    begin
      lblRestamAgenda.Font.Color := clBlack;
      lblRestamAgenda.Caption    := ('Restam '+IntToStr(Total));
    end;
  end;
  Repaint;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.MudaCorEntrada(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmTelaPrincipal.MudaCorEntrada(Sender); <== Esse é o evento de entrada dos Memos
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.MudaCorSaida(Sender: TObject);
begin
  frmTelaPrincipal.MudaCorSaida(Sender);   <== Esse é o evento de Saida dos Memos 
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  btnCancelarClick(Sender);
  DataModuleGeral2.qryPesquisaAndamentos.Close;

  FreeAndNil(frmAndamentoProcessual);
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.HintHidePause := 5550;
  Position := poScreenCenter;

  DataModuleRelatorios.cdsImagens_.Close;
  DataModuleRelatorios.cdsImagens_.CreateDataSet;
  DataModuleRelatorios.cdsImagens_.Open;

  dbcUsuarioResponsavel.Items.Clear;
  DataModuleGeral.tbUsuariosConsulta.First;
end;


procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (key=#13) and not (Copy(TControl(ActiveControl).Name,1,3)='dbm') then
    key := #0;
end;

procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DataModuleRelatorios.cdsImagens_.Open;
  DataModuleRelatorios.cdsImagens_.EmptyDataSet;

  PesquisaAndamentos(vCampoProcesso);

  // Controle de Acesso - Inclusão
  if Copy(DataModuleGeral.qryUsuarioAtivoANDAMENTOS.AsString,2,1)  = 'S' then
    btnNovoAndamento.Enabled    := True
  else btnNovoAndamento.Enabled := False;
  // Controle de Acesso - Edição
  if Copy(DataModuleGeral.qryUsuarioAtivoANDAMENTOS.AsString,3,1)  = 'S' then
    btnAlterarAndamento.Enabled    := True
  else btnAlterarAndamento.Enabled := False;
  // Controle de Acesso - Exclusaão
  if Copy(DataModuleGeral.qryUsuarioAtivoANDAMENTOS.AsString,4,1)  = 'S' then
    btnExcluirAndamento.Enabled    := True
  else btnExcluirAndamento.Enabled := False;
  // Controle de Acesso - Publicações
  if Copy(DataModuleGeral.qryUsuarioAtivoPUBLICACOES.AsString,1,1) = 'S' then
    btnPublicacao.Enabled    := True
  else btnPublicacao.Enabled := False;
  // Controle de Acesso - Consultas
  if Copy(DataModuleGeral.qryUsuarioAtivoCONSULTAS.AsString,1,1)   = 'S' then
    btnConsultas.Enabled    := True
  else btnConsultas.Enabled := False;

  lblRestam.Caption := 'Restam '+IntToStr(dbmObservacao2.MaxLength);

  dbcFaseProcesso.DataField := vCampoFase;
  dbgPesquisaAndamentos.SetFocus;
end;

end.
```

Esse abaixo é como eu chamo o form

```
  if frmManutencaoProcessos = Nil then
  begin
    frmManutencaoProcessos        := TfrmManutencaoProcessos.Create(self);
    frmManutencaoProcessos.Parent := frmTelaPrincipal;
  end;
  frmAndamentoProcessual.Show;
```

Mudei a forma e Criar o Form não sei se tem alguma coias diferente com relação a criação, mas ainda não está funcionado como deveria quando eu crio o form do modo acima.

Imagem do Object Inspector do `TMemo`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisar de mais alguma informação é só pedir que eu posto.

Comment: Não entendi o ForcaEntradaClick. A princípio, não é necessário. Está atribuído a algum handler de evento? A propriedade TabStop do Memo é true?

Comment: O ForcaEntradaClick é uma gambiarra criada para poder entra no memo clicando com o botão direito do mouse. pois não está entrando normalmente.

Comment: chegou a investigar o funcionamento desta rotina? `frmTelaPrincipal.MudaCorEntrada(Sender);`

Comment: A Rotina  `frmTelaPrincipal.MudaCorEntrada(Sender);` está funcionado corretamente para todos os campos onde a rotina é aplicado.

Comment: Após o `SetFocus`, use `PostMessage(TMemo(Sender).Handle, WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0);`

Comment: O nome do componente da imagem é `dbmDescricao_PublicacaoIncl`, mas não achei essa referência no código. Poste como está a aba `Events` do `TMemo` específico. Percebi que na `procedure TfrmAndamentoProcessual.FormShow(Sender: TObject);` está manipulando o Foco `dbgPesquisaAndamentos.SetFocus;` se você tiver algum evento do TMemo setado para `FormShow` então poderá ser esse o problema, por exemplo se no `OnClick` do `TMemo` estiver `FormShow`, então toda vez que clicar no `Memo` quem receberá o foco será o `dbgPesquisaAndamentos`.

Comment: É porque eu redefini o nome do Componente para `dbm_Observacao` porque está muito grande.